# Seams not showing up when marked

Tags: uv

I'm trying to mark seams on the seat cushion but when I do the edges I've selected don't turn red. Any ideas? I've attached the blender file below, thanks

[image: Seam Example]

[Blender File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Xf0FIr_z-2zxb2324YryCZgLtkZHVTc1)

Comment: If those edges are already marked as any type (e.g. sharp, Freestyle, crease) the color change once marking seams might not be obvious. All the edges were marked as sharp or freestyle (color depends on theme) in the screenshot above so probably that's why seam marks aren't visible. Try unwrapping and see if UV map turns into islands or disable visibility for any type in the Edit mode > Properties shelf.

Comment: It is also possible to adjust which edge values are shown. Look in the [mesh display](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/mesh_display.html) panel.